# Generating a docx file using Pandoc: images missing! Due to multiple requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, pandoc

I'm generating a markdown document using my Rails 4.2 app which includes images that are on the same server (in the `public` folder).

Using pandoc (pandoc-ruby 1.0.0), I want to convert the document into various formats, especially HTML (to preview it in the browser) and DOCX (to download it).

The preview in the browser works perfect. But when converting to DOCX, the images aren't included. I guess this is due to multiple requests to referenced images while pandoc is generating the document.

I have already experimented with setting `allow_concurrency` to `true`, but this didn't solve the problem. Also, it happens on both the development and the production environment (while in development, it takes a long time, and in production it doesn't - maybe due to some differences in timeout limits?).

I have already found a way to solve my problem by not referencing the images using an URL, but by embedding it as base64 string into the document. But this for sure can't be the solution of choice, as it tends to bloat up the HTML document a lot. Also, on production, I already get `RuntimeError (Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes)` from pretty small embedded images. So I have to find a real solution.

Comment: You are right, this solves the problem. Thank you! Still it would be interesting to know where the problem's lying.

Comment: are you on the newest pandoc version? I remember there once being a problem with docx and remote images... anyhow, it's far more efficient grabbing them directly from disk...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the images by file path instead of url if they are on the same server.